# ClassCastException while using opsForHash.scan() in redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, classcastexception, jedis

> ClassCastException occurs when I try to scan a large number of keys
>   using opsForHash.scan() method. I am using Jedis 2.6.2 and I face this
>   error only when the number of keys to be searched is large(~100,000).
>   I have read solutions to this problem online and most of them are
>   suggesting that the problem occurs due to connection pooling.

I am using Spring integration in my project and have set use-pool attribute as true(in JedisConnectionFactory) even though it is the default option.
Since spring is supposed to manage the connections with redis, why am I still having this issue?
Please suggest.

[image]

**This is the Spring Configuration file I am using :**

[image]

**This is the java code where i am executing scan() :**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. After searching a lot on the internet, I found that the problem occurs due to connection pooling problems. As you have mentioned, you have set use-pool to be true in the spring configuration.
I by passed this problem by setting pooling as false. It turned out that I didn't need pooling and after that the problem didn't occur. 
You can try this solution if you don't explicitly need pooling.
Here is the code snippet:

```
<bean id="jedisConnFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:hostName="" p:port="6379" p:usePool="false" />
```

Hope it helps!